# text_area submit issue using Rich Text Editor which outputs HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce, editor

Using tiny_mce from https://github.com/kete/tiny_mce
to be able to change the format of the text, the problem is once its submitted it sends the html to my comments and its not getting translated and just outputs to plain html shown below

```
<ul> <li><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>hello&nbsp;</strong></span></li> <li><span style="text-decoration: underline;">test</span></li> <li><span style="text-decoration: underline;">est</span></li> <li><span style="text-decoration: underline;">est<br /></span></li> </ul>
```

How do i get rails to translate the html so it displays boldness etc..
I've tried putting it in HTML tags `<html><%= comment.body %></html>` which does not work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `raw` helper:

```
<%=raw comment.body %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should sanitize the input in your model using a `before_validation` filter.

I like `gem 'sanitize'`, with it you can `self.body = Sanitize.clean( self.body, Sanitize::Config::RESTRICTED )`

Then you can safely use `<%= raw comment.body %>` or `<%= comment.body.html_safe %>` to display the HTML.